# Can't import referance images into Draw Mode in the 2D animation template

Tags: draw-mode

Hi getting my head around the program. I can't get my reference image out of Object mode into Draw Mode. I bring them in Via the Add button in Drawing mode and I've tried to bring them in in Drawing mode Via the import menu drop down in the File menu but I get reaction in the Collection viewer but see nothing on the screen in object mode Jpegs come in I can transform and edit but cant move to drawing mode to outline my sketches.

Comment: Did you try switching to the stroke layer?